# Show only child categories of current category page

Tags: php, wordpress, children

I am having a hard time getting the children for the current category page. For instance I am on currently on the page for category 4. It seems to only be pulling it's siblings right now instead of the the children.  I do not want the siblings in there, just only the children. Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 $this_category = get_the_category();
 $child_categories=get_categories( array( 'parent' => $this_category->cat_ID,));
     foreach($child_categories as $category) { 
         $category_url = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
         $category_name = $category->cat_name;
         $category_description = $category->description;
 ?>
 <div class="col3">
     <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id, array(365, 165)); ?>">
     <h3><a href="<?php echo $category_url?>"><?php echo $category_name?></a></h3>
     <p><?php echo $category_description?></p>
     <a class="view-more" href="<?php echo $category_url?>">View More</a>
 </div>
 <?php
 }?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after realizing I was using the wrong wordpress _get functions.

```
                $this_category = get_category( $cat );
                $child_categories=get_categories( array( 'child_of' => $this_category->cat_ID,));
                foreach($child_categories as $category) { 
                        $category_url = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
                        $category_name = $category->cat_name;
                        $category_description = $category->description;
                    ?>
                <div class="col3">
                    <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id, array(365, 165)); ?>">
                  <h3><a href="<?php echo $category_url?>"><?php echo $category_name?></a></h3>
                  <p><?php echo $category_description?></p>
                  <a class="view-more" href="<?php echo $category_url?>">View More</a>
                </div>
                    <?php
                }?>
```